# How can i send a value to another file and then increment the same amount of times as i make the code iterate?

Tags: excel, vba, increment

Basically i want to increment the value in cell N19 of my sourcesheet when this value gets sent over to column L of dados.xlsm
let's say i write the following in cell N19 "A120" and choose 4 repetitions
I want the following numbers to be seen in column L of dados : "A120" and then "A121" (in the cell below) ,"A122" (in the cell below), "A123" (in the cell below), "A124" (in the cell below)

basically i want to increment it the same amount of times as there is repetitions

The types of values cell N19 will be receiving are always something along the lines of "C251"
Oh and i would also like to make it so that if the user writes something like "D999" and chooses 2 or more repetitions the values will be sent like "D999","D1","D2"... (Basically 999 is the max number)

I tried the following code but i have no clue on how to implement the function i described earlier

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim repeticoes As Integer
    repeticoes = Me.ComboBox1.value

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cavidadeValue As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim tipoDePecaComboBox As Object
    Dim tipoDeProblemaComboBox As Object
    Dim cavidadesComboBox As Object
    Dim semanaComboBox As Object
    Dim anoComboBox As Object
    Dim tipoAnaliseBox As Object
    Dim problemaBox1 As Object

    ' Definição do sheet source (Sheet1) e do target (Dados)
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("W:\Quality\70. Leaks\Leak Files\Teardown YF\YF\teste\dados.xlsm")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets("Dados")
    Set tipoAnaliseBox = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("tipoanaliseBox").Object
    Set problemaBox1 = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("problemaComboBox").Object

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To repeticoes
        Select Case True
            '----------------------------------------------------------3/4------------------------------------------------------------------
            Case tipoAnaliseBox = "3/4"
            

                sourceSheet.Unprotect password:="567"

                ' Encontra a próxima linha disponível começando na segunda linha da coluna B no targetSheet
                lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1

                ' A linha abaixo vai buscar o valor do cavidadeBox e transfere-o em formato de texto
                ' É necessário fazer isto pois como certas cavidades têm o formato de x/x/x, o Excel assume que as cavidades
                ' deviam estar em formato de data, e nós não queremos isso.
                cavidadeValue = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("cavidadeBox").Object.Text

                ' Transferência dos valores do sourceSheet para o targetSheet no arquivo de destino
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "B").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "B").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("tipoAnaliseBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "F").value = sourceSheet.Range("R14").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("genComboBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "D").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("modelComboBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "E").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("pecaComboBox").Object.value
                If sourceSheet.Range("E21").value = "" Then
                    targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "H").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("semanaBox").Object.value & "-" & sourceSheet.OLEObjects("anoBox").Object.value
                Else
                    targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "H").value = sourceSheet.Range("E21").value
                End If
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "G").value = sourceSheet.Range("K14").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "I").NumberFormat = "@" ' Formatação do valor das cavidades como texto
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "I").value = cavidadeValue
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "J").value = sourceSheet.Range("L19").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "K").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("problemaComboBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "L").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "L").value = sourceSheet.Range("N19").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "M").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("tipoamostraBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "N").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("turnoBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "O").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("comboBoxanalisador").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "P").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "P").value = sourceSheet.Range("O12").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "Q").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "Q").value = sourceSheet.Range("S19").value

                ' Salva o arquivo de destino
                targetWorkbook.Save

            '----------------------------------------------------------Fixture------------------------------------------------------------------
            Case tipoAnaliseBox = "Fixture"
          

                sourceSheet.Unprotect password:="567"

                ' Encontra a próxima linha disponível começando na segunda linha da coluna B no targetSheet
                lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1

                ' A linha abaixo vai buscar o valor do cavidadeBox e transfere-o em formato de texto
                ' É necessário fazer isto pois como certas cavidades têm o formato de x/x/x, o Excel assume que as cavidades
                ' deviam estar em formato de data, e nós não queremos isso.
                cavidadeValue = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("cavidadeBox").Object.Text

                ' Transferência dos valores do sourceSheet para o targetSheet no arquivo de destino
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "B").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "B").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("tipoAnaliseBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "F").value = sourceSheet.Range("R14").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("genComboBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "D").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("modelComboBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "E").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("pecaComboBox").Object.value
                If sourceSheet.Range("E21").value = "" Then
                    targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "H").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("semanaBox").Object.value & "-" & sourceSheet.OLEObjects("anoBox").Object.value
                Else
                    targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "H").value = sourceSheet.Range("E21").value
                End If
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "G").value = sourceSheet.Range("K14").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "I").NumberFormat = "@" ' Formatação do valor das cavidades como texto
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "I").value = cavidadeValue
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "J").value = sourceSheet.Range("L19").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "K").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("problemaComboBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "L").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "L").value = sourceSheet.Range("N19").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "M").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("tipoamostraBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "N").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("turnoBox").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "O").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("comboBoxanalisador").Object.value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "P").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "P").value = sourceSheet.Range("O12").value
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "Q").NumberFormat = "@"
                targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "Q").value = sourceSheet.Range("S19").value

                ' Salva o arquivo de destino
                targetWorkbook.Save
        End Select
    Next i

    ' Fecha o arquivo de destino sem exibição
    targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Exibe uma mensagem de sucesso ao usuário
    MsgBox "Valores transferidos com sucesso!", vbInformation, "Sucesso"

    ' Fecha a janela do formulário
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

If you require a better explanation or more information about my issue feel free to ask and ill do my best to give you a better explanation

Thank you for reading.

Comment: So it always a single letter followed by numbers?

Comment: What's the difference between "3/4" and "Fixture" ?

Comment: Yes it appears to be a single letter followed by numbers up until 999

Right now there is no difference between "3/4" and "Fixture" however i was going to add an If statement because in "3/4" there are certain fields the user needs to fill and in "Fixture" some of those fields are not required to be filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to create a set of sequence values.  Eg:

```vb
'Return a Collection containing `num` values, each beginning with the
'  non-numeric prefix from `txtStart`, with an incrementing numeric suffix
Function Sequence(txtStart As String, num As Long)
    Dim i As Long, nStart As Long, prefix As String, c As String
    Set Sequence = New Collection
    For i = 1 To Len(txtStart)
        c = Mid(txtStart, i, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then Exit For
        prefix = prefix & c 'extract all non-numeric characters from the start of the string
    Next i
    nStart = CLng(Mid(txtStart, Len(prefix) + 1)) 'first numeric value
    For i = nStart To (nStart + num - 1)
        Sequence.Add prefix & 1 + ((i - 1) Mod 999) '## cap max numeric part to 999
    Next i
End Function
```

In your code (relevant parts only):

```vb
    Dim repeticoes As Long, seq As Collection, lastRow As Range
    '...
    '...
    
    repeticoes = Me.ComboBox1.Value

    'generate the sequence
    Set seq = Sequence(sourceSheet.Range("N19").Value, repeticoes) 
    
    '...
    '...
    For i = 1 To seq.Count
        
        Set lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow 'next empty row
        '...
        '...
        lastRow.Columns("L").Value = seq(i)
        '...
        '...
    Next i
```

FYI - instead of doing something like this repeatedly:

```vb
targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").NumberFormat = "@"
targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").value = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("genComboBox").Object.value
```

You can make a Sub:

```vb
Sub SetTextValue(c As Range, v)
    c.NumberFormat = "@"
    c.Value = v
End Sub
```

...and then call it like

```
SetTextValue targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C"), sourceSheet.OLEObjects("genComboBox").Object.value
```

Comment: Thank you so much,it works just like i want it too!

Comment: If this answers your question, please flag as "Accepted", to help anyone coming along later with a similar question to see there's a working solution.